# Uber API: API method/CVS sheet to get full rides info for each rider in the company

Tags: uber-api

We have an Uber company-level account with a lot of autos working in the Uber application (~ 50-100 depends on several cases).

Now we are building analytic app, that aggregates information about each car earnings/rides for each our driver.

Do we need to get "Uber for Business" to get aggregated information for each driver/rides from https://developer.uber.com/docs/businesses/data-automation/data-download, or we need to build application, where each our rider needs to authorize to grant access to its information with bearer token, and iterate over each token on endpoints https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-payments-get and https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-trips-get?

I think, that last method is the crooked nail for us.

Comment: I do not have specific advice for you, but just wanted to point out that the Driver API is in limited access, so you might not be able to build on that API.

Comment: @KyleDavis thanks for reply, but, we need the right solution. We always contact our regional representative of the Uber, and he directed us to the StackOverflow

Comment: If you determine that driver API would provide what you need, then your regional contact may be able to help you get approved.